# how to Pass Raw Json to post request in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hi I am new to swift please spare me.

I need to post to particular API but the api is not a fan of `key` `value` pair the api expect `raw json` as post data

I use this library [here](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) to make post request.

this is my code

```
func postItem(itemname: String, itemnumber: Int, itemcode:String, url:String, baseURL:String, completion: (result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> ()){
        var dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>!


        var params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> =  ["parentItem": ["itemname":itemname,"itemnumber":itemnumber,"itemcode":code]]
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
        let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        var request = HTTPTask()
        request.requestSerializer = JSONRequestSerializer()
        request.requestSerializer.headers[headerKey] = getToken() //example of adding a header value


        request.POST(url, parameters: params, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in

            if response.responseObject != nil {
                let data = response.responseObject as NSData
                var error: NSError?
                dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>;

                completion(result: dict)
            }

            },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in
                dict = ["error" : "error" ]
                completion(result: dict)

        })

    }
```

i need to pass this kind of raw json in api

eg. `{"parentItem": {"itemname":"Cocoa","itemnumber":123,"itemcode":"cocoa-12-A"}}`

but when I println my params because it is dictionary it generate something like

```
["parentItem": ["itemname"="Cocoa"; "itemnumber"=123; "itemcode"="cocoa-12-A"]]
```

I just couldn't convert the params to JSON because the library I'm using is expecting dictionary and I'm having a hard time creating my own class.

could anyone help me? any comments and suggestion would do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use Alamofire framework ? It's pretty good and sends standard json

Comment: that's pretty detailed library I will give it a shot. thanks for suggestion